# ¿Como soluciono el error de "Aplicación se Detuvo" en Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

estoy desarrollando una App en Android Studio y cuando ejecuto la aplicación mi primera pantalla es un Splash Screen y cuando se terminan los 4seg del Splash me aparece en la pantalla que se detuvo no se a que se deba este error si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradeceria
Este es el error que me manda al momneto de compilarlo

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.aguil.proyecto, PID: 25697
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.aguil.proyecto/com.example.aguil.proyecto.Menu}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2659)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:467)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                  at com.example.aguil.proyecto.Menu.onCreate(Menu.java:11)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6672)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2612)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
               Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 298598412 byte allocation with 9356792 free bytes and 178MB until OOM
                  at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:620)
                  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:455)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1152)
                  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:724)
                  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:575)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:854)
                  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:928)
                  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4177)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:578)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:574)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:570)
                  at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.<init>(ConstraintLayout.java:566)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:467) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                  at com.example.aguil.proyecto.Menu.onCreate(Menu.java:11) 
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6672) 
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2612) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

Comment: Esta parte del error: `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>` parece indicar que estás intentando inflar algún menú que no existe en los recursos de la App. Por otra parte, tu App parece que está usando demasiada memoria: `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 298598412 byte allocation with 9356792 free bytes and 178MB until OOM...` Quizá necesite ser optimizada, pues es un punto neurálgico en cualquier app.

Comment: Como podria solucionar ambos errores, lo que pasa es que apenas comienzo en Android

Comment: Es difícil poder ayudarte en este caso, sobre todo porque el mensaje de error es amplio y puede que varias cosas anden mal en tu App. Para comenzar te recomendaría que empieces creando una App con el mismo Wizard de Android Studio y que luego vayas modificándola poco a poco. Es una de los mejores maneras de aprender cómo funcionan las cosas, sobre todo al comienzo.

Comment: Lo raro es que solo pasa cuando pongo una imagen de fondo por que cuando la quito se ejecuta de manera correcta

Comment: Puede entonces que esa imagen sea demasiado grande, o que no estés indicando bien la ruta de dicha imagen. En cualquier caso, conviene que [edites la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/173658/edit), poniendo el código donde agregas la imagen e indicando dónde se supone que debería estar dicha imagen.

Comment: Era la imagen que era muy grandes, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Cuando aparecen esos mensajes de error tan largos en Java, es importante fijarse en las líneas que empiezan por `Caused by...`

En tu caso tienes varias que dicen algo parecido a esto:

> `Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2:
>   Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>`

y luego una que dice:

> `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 298598412
>   byte allocation with 9356792 free bytes and 178MB until OOM`

Puede que tengas algún problema de intentar una imagen de demasiado grande, o de incluir algún recurso que no está bien referenciado en tu carpeta `res`.

El mensaje `OutOfMemoryError` es preocupante, y significa que sin duda hay algo que deber ser optimizado en tu App (un recurso demasiado grande o un proceso que tarda demasiado tiempo o que es llamado demasiadas veces, etc).